# Need to Deactivate the On-Click function if hovering on other link

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on a DropDown menu and i added hovering effect for the Dropdown items but what i am strugging is when i am click on a link then the dropdown menu opens  but when i am hovering then that click function is still activate.

Please see the attached image for more clarity & let me know if you require more details :
[image]

HTML CODE :

```html
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
}
```

JS CODE :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.navbar-nav li a').filter(function() {
   return this.href == location.href
  }).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $('.navbar-nav li a').click(
    function() {
     $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass(
       'active');
    })
 });
```

Comment: You have to add your html and js code in order to get any help.

Comment: As @dganenco said we need your code. For now I only can suggest you to look after a mousout event which close the open submenu when the cursor leave this submenu container element.

Comment: Added...Can you please suggest code as i ma new to front end

Comment: Also note, when clicking the active link, than the dropdown should close, right? I would suggest your remove the css hovering and use JS only, but on click check if item is active or not.

Comment: Can you suggest the code pls

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="myDIV">
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn active">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>
<button class="btn">4</button>
<button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

CSS: Design your own

Try this pure JavaScript code

```
        // Get the container element
        var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");

        // Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
        var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

        // Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
     btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
     current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
    });
    }
```

Comment: this also not working..What i am looking for is that i want to click function on the dropdown link only want to see the menu if hover goes to there.Please suggest if you have idea